# wanted to return root of tree node with latest addition of a node intact

Tags: c++, binary-tree, implementation

The issue: the root node is being set to null and the actual addition of nodes in the tree doesn't quite happen:

Client program:

```
int main () {

int arr [] = {15, 10, 100, 5, 13, 90, 80, 50, 10, 5, 3};
int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);

using namespace btree;
//create an instance of btree::tree;
btree::tree* tree = new btree::tree();
btree::btnode* root = tree->get_root_btnode();

//create tree
tree->create_btree (root, arr, len);

delete tree;
return 0;
```

}

The member functions (used in client program) looks like follows:

```
//creates a complete tree
void tree::create_btree (btnode* root, int arr[], int len) {

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        add_a_btnode (root, arr[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "Tree creation successful!!" << std::endl;
}

void tree::add_a_btnode (btnode* root, int data) {
    ///check if tree is empty
    btnode *current = root;
    if (!current) {
        btnode* newbtnode = new btnode(data);
        root = newbtnode;
        return;
    }

    if (current->get_left_btnode() != nullptr) {
        //can we add it as right child of current btnode?
        if (current->get_right_btnode() != nullptr) {
            //recurse
            add_a_btnode (current->get_left_btnode(), current->get_data());
        } else {
            btnode* newbtnode = new btnode(data);
            current->m_right = newbtnode;
        }
    } else {
        btnode* newbtnode = new btnode(data);
        current->m_left = newbtnode;
    }
    std::cout << "a root btnode is added with data: " << data << endl;
}
```

and in last the member functions which i expected to return me the root node (which doesn't quite happen :( any help):

```
btnode* tree::get_root_btnode () { return m_root_btnode; }
```

Comment: Ideally your "client side" shouldn't even know `btnode` exists, let alone have to pass one to your member functions to make things happen. Also, from the "client" perspective, your `create_btree` would probably do better as a constructor. And lastly, why are you allocating your tree dynamically from the client side??

Comment: @scohe001 i understand this is not an ideal design. but it would be really helpful if you suggest me any wrong doings wrt passing pointer and how am handling them.btw, here is how output looks "Tree creation successful!!
No elem in tree!"

Comment: Could you please post the constructor for `tree`? Where does `m_root_btnode` get initialized?

Comment: btnode* tree::m_root_btnode = nullptr;
 
tree::tree () {}

tree::~tree() {
 m_root_btnode = nullptr;
} // i have declared m_root_btnode to be static

Comment: I don't see the point of the naked `root` pointer in the first place. The `tree` should house that, ideally not exposing it to the outside world. If you have to, you probably designed something wrong. And fyi, using references to pointers for your arguments to some of these will *considerably* simplify their implementation. Just saying.

Comment: @WhozCraig  and scohe001 your suggestions are noted. If i have no option but to only change the design, i will do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
if (!current) {
    btnode* newbtnode = new btnode(data);
    root = newbtnode;
    return;
}
```

You create root node and save it to variable `root`. But it is a local variable, and in fact you don't modify the tree object at all.

Instead, you should save it to variable inside your `tree` class. So it would be something like that:

```
if (!current) {
    m_root_btnode = new btnode(data);
    return;
}
```

Btw. Why do you pass pointer to root as argument, when the functions are methods of `tree` class and you have access to original root variable? This would be much cleaner, and you wouldn't make that mistake then.

Comment: in fact, what you said is just what i wanted to do. guess i have to work on the code thoroughly. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `create_btree` function as follows:

```
void tree::create_btree(int arr[], int len) {
    if (len > 0) {
        m_root_btnode = new btnode(arr[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        add_a_btnode(m_root_btnode, arr[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "Tree creation successful!!" << std::endl;
}
```

There are many issues with your code, but this is what I'd start with.